# MVC - How to download a csv file using ajax in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, export-to-csv

I have a problem in downloading csv file using *$.ajax();* code.

I have a controller which is returning the file as below.

```
public ActionResult ExportEx()
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table>");            
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        sb.Append("<td>1</td>");
        sb.Append("<td>2</td>");
        sb.Append("<td>3</td>");
        sb.Append("<td>4</td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");
        sb.Append("<table>");         

    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=student_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".xls");
    this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    return File(buffer, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

I have index.cshtml file as below

```
<input type="submit" value="Export To Excel" title="Export To excel" />        

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".tt").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/ExportEx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) { },
            complete: function (data) { }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I call using `<a class="tt" href="@Url.Action("ExportEx", new { })">export</a>` I can  download csv file. But through `$.ajax` call i can not download.

Kindly help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do this through ajax?  Couldn't you just use an actionLink to download the file?

Comment: I need to pass some dynamic values to action method. So, I am using ajax call

Comment: You could use hidden form elements to pass dynamic values to the controller.  I don't think ajax is the right approach here.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $('button').click(function () {
            window.location.href = '/Home/ExportEx';
        });
```